# What does "THUMB" macro do in ARM-linux code?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, thumb

I am looking at head.S ARM linux code.
I know what thumb mode is. But there is one line such as `THUMB(it eq)` and it is a predefined macro as `#define THUMB(x...) x`
The *dotdotdot* is actually written.

Please tell me what the macro does.

```
ENTRY(stext)
  setmode PSR_F_BIT | PSR_I_BIT | SVC_MODE, r9 @ ensure svc mode
                                               @ and irqs disabled
  mrc p15, 0, r9, c0, c0      @ get processor id
  bl__lookup_processor_type   @ r5=procinfo r9=cpuid
  movs r10, r5                @ invalid processor (r5=0)? 
  THUMB( iteq )               @ force fixup-able long branch encoding
  beq __error_p               @ yes, error 'p'
```

Comment: See http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0210c/CACBCAAE.html.

Answer (score 2):

`THUMB()` an `ARM()` preprocessor macros are used to conditionally compile the source assembly depending on the target instruction set. If the kernel is being compiled for ARM target, THUMB() macro is no-op. On the contrary, if the kernel is being compiled for THUMB, THUMB() macro is expanded to its arguments.

Comment: See: [unified.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/unified.h) and [assembler.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/assembler.h) for more conditionalized macros.  This allows the same code to be used for either *Thumb2* (advanced *thumb*) and regular *ARM* kernels.  The macros make the assembler (*head.S* in this case), read more easily.  Usually a bunch of `#ifdef ... #endif` are distracting.  As 90%+ of the code is identical, it is easier to maintain one file instead of two.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it now. one thing that bothers me is "it eq" or "it ne" instructions which I can't figure out. But at least for now, I think I can skip thumb things

Comment: `IT` is a special Thumb-2 instruction that allows conditional execution of up to 4 subsequent instructions. There are multiple ways of making a conditional branch in Thumb-2 mode: 16-bit conditional short branch instruction or IT + long branch instruction. In this example explicit `it eq` forces assembler to use the encoding with long offset.

Anyway, it makes sense only for Thumb target. Please, mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question.